# Hook CTRL+ALT+TAB

Tags: wpf, keyboard-hook

I've made a WPF application and I was able to hook some of the windows combinations. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> is hooked and it is doing nothing when my application is running (as expected). The problem is when I press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> I get the same effect as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.
Do you guys have any idea on how to hook this kind of combination?

**EDIT:**

I have already successfully hooked <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. I do want to hook <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. I've tried this [project example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31261/Full-Screen-WPF-Application-with-a-Low-Level-Keybo) to make this happen.

Here's the code that makes the hook:

```
private static IntPtr KeyboardHookHandler(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, 
                  ref KBHookStruct lParam){
if (nCode == 0)
{
    if (((lParam.vkCode == 0x09) && (lParam.flags == 0x20)) ||  // Alt+Tab
    ((lParam.vkCode == 0x1B) && (lParam.flags == 0x20)) ||      // Alt+Esc
    ((lParam.vkCode == 0x1B) && (lParam.flags == 0x00)) ||      // Ctrl+Esc
    ((lParam.vkCode == 0x5B) && (lParam.flags == 0x01)) ||      // Left Windows Key
    ((lParam.vkCode == 0x5C) && (lParam.flags == 0x01)) ||      // Right Windows Key
    ((lParam.vkCode == 0x73) && (lParam.flags == 0x20)) ||      // Alt+F4
    ((lParam.vkCode == 0x20) && (lParam.flags == 0x20)))        // Alt+Space
    {
        return new IntPtr(1);
    }
}

return CallNextHookEx(hookPtr, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);}
```

Comment: Sorry I do not get your question. Which one you want to hook "Alt+Tab" or "Ctrl+Alt+Tab"? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1**

You can try like below it work for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  + <kbd>TAB</kbd>  and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
private void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.Modifiers & (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift)) == (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("CTRL + SHIFT + TAB trapped");
   }

   if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("CTRL + TAB trapped");
   }
}
```

**Answer 2**

should look something like:

```
((lParam.flags & 33 == 33) && (lParam.flags & 22 == 22))
```

32 and 22 are arbitrary in this example. You need to figure out what values ALT and CTRL actually are. They will be 1, 2, 4 ... 16, 32 etc. so that they can be OR'ed together into a single value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've already tryed that but it doesnt work for CTRL+ALT combinations. :\

Comment: Did you try Answer 2?

Comment: Yes I have and no luck. I think it might be because it is a "special" combination just like Ctrl+Alt+Del and that is why its not working.